# C# find all open Excel sheets and kill only one

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I'm trying to find all the open excel workbooks and kill one particular one. 
But when i loop through and print the title of the workbook , It just display only one ,though i have opened multiple workbooks.

```
         //Excel Application Object
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application oExcelApp;
            this.Activate();

            System.Diagnostics.Process[] AllProcesses = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("excel");
   foreach (Process ExcelProcess in AllProcesses)
            {   
              //Display the name of the object.
              MessageBox.Show(oExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.FullName);

             //if (myHashtable.ContainsKey(ExcelProcess.Id) == false)
                // ExcelProcess.Kill();
            }
```

Comment: There's generally only one instance of the Excel process running, regardless of the number of workbooks.  I'm not familiar with C# but you basically want: foreach (ExcelWorkbookObj in oExcelApp.Workbooks.  Then if ExcelWorkbookObj != "whatever" then ExcelWorkbookObj.Close

Comment: Either you have not posted the complete code snippet or you are not using `ExcelProcess`, the loop variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
 string bookTitle = "test"; // The book title that you want to close.
 Process[] AllProcesses = Process.GetProcessesByName("excel");
 foreach (var process in AllProcesses)
 {
    string tempTitle = process.MainWindowTitle.Split('-')[1].TrimStart();
    if (bookTitle == tempTitle)
        {
            process.Kill();
        }
 }
```

Comment: No,only the book named to `bookTitle`.

Comment: It works fine. I was trying something similar but it didn't work for :( . Thanks for the help !